# Unable to use react native Bluetoothel

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, bluetooth

I have added react-native-ble-plx in my app. I have also linked it using react native link cmd. I have follwed all required step provided in the lib documents. But  Its not working. I never ask for user permission and it gives error Deivce is not authorized to use BluetoothLE. Here is my code for

```
AndroidManifest.xml

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.smartdeviceiot">
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
   <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-sdk
                 android:minSdkVersion="18"
                 android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
```

> DeviceSearch.js
>
> import colors from '../constants/colors'; 
>   import images from '../constants/images'; 
>   import { Button, Icon, Text, Container, Header,
>   Left, Body, Title, Right } from 'native-base'; 
>   import { HomeStyle } from './styles/home'; 
>   import { BleManager } from'react-native-ble-plx' 
>   class DevicesSearch extends Component {
>       static navigationOptions = {
>           title: 'DevicesSearch'
>       };
>       constructor(props) {
>           super(props);
>           const manager = new BleManager();
>           this.state = {
>           };
>       }
>       componentWillMount() {
>       }
>       render() {
>           return (
>               
>               
>                       
>                            >this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}>
>                           
>                           
>                       
>                       
>                           DevicesSearch
>                       
>                       
>               
>                   
>                       
>                           
>                           Search Devices
>                           
>                       
>                   
>               
>           );
>       }
>       scanAndConnect  = () => {
>           alert('asd')
>           console.log('cal');
>           this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
>             this.info("Scanning...");
>             console.log(device);
>
> ```
>       if (error) {
>         this.error(error.message);
>         return
>       }
>
>       if (device.name ==='MyDevice') {
>         this.info("Connecting to Tappy");
>         this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
>
>         device.connect()
>           .then((device) => {
>             this.info("Discovering services and characteristics");
>             return device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()
>           })
>           .then((device) => {
>             this.info(device.id);
>             device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService('12ab', '34cd',
> ```
>
> 'aGVsbG8gbWlzcyB0YXBweQ==')
>                     .then((characteristic) => {
>                       this.info(characteristic.value);
>                       return 
>                     })
>                 })
>                 .catch((error) => {
>                   this.error(error.message)
>                 })
>              }
>          });
>       } } function mapStateToProps(state) {
>       //pass the providers
>       return {
>       } } /* Map Actions to Props */ function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) >{
>       return {
>           actions: bindActionCreators({
>           }, dispatch)
>       }; } export default connect(
>       mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )(DevicesSearch);

if my bluetooth is turn off the code console.log me that bluetooth is off, but when its on it log me me that device is not auth to use bluetooth. I have also tired to use AndroidPermission lib but no success. it doesnt take permission from user

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to explicitly ask the user for the permission. I had the same problem and I solved it by adding this code in a separate file:

```
export async function requestLocationPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, {
        title: 'Location permission for bluetooth scanning',
        message: 'wahtever',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    ); 
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log('Location permission for bluetooth scanning granted');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('Location permission for bluetooth scanning revoked');
      return false;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
    return false;
  }
}
```

and then when I need to scan, before the actual scan code I do the following:

```
  scanAndConnect() {
    const permission = requestLocationPermission();
    if (permission) {        
      ...here I scan because the user has given permission
```

Comment: small correction you may need to await requestLocationPermission() and scanAndConnect should be async. And also fine_location worked for us not coarse

Comment: On newer versions of Android, you might need these permissions: `PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, `PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_SCAN` and `PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT`

PermissionsAndroid has a `requestMultiple` method that could be useful.

Comment: On `targetSdkVersion = 29`, `PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, when targeting newer android devices you must ask for 'ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION' instead of 'ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions